# Quake 2 network problem on localhost

Tags: windows-7, quake-2

In a bout of nostalgia I installed Quake 2 again a few weeks ago and started playing through it, one level at a time in the evenings.

Yesterday thought a weird problem started. When I load my single-player game (or start a new one) the "network problem" icon keeps flashing in the upper left corner. And movement in the game has become very... imprecise. It's like I'm moving in tiny jumps, often incorrectly even. Playing is impossible.

My system is Windows 7, and I haven't changed anything recently. Any ideas why this is happening? Rebooting doesn't help. Google doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Hah, problem solved. Turns out I had an ancient version of the game. Updating to 3.20 solved everything.